# Need to store the data on the server instead on the browser window/tab on client side

Tags: java, servlets

We have requirement that we need to store the data on the server using java servlet instead of using the session storage which is used to store the on the browser window/tab on client side.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to do that, below are some common ways for the same.

1. If your data is file then you need to see File Upload using Servlet API.
2. You can use JDBC API in your Servlet to write data into relational databases like
   MySQL, PostgreSQL in tabular format and can retrieve later on as well.

If you can describe what kind of data you want to store at server side then answer can be given more in detail.